# Integral of $\int \tan^2 x \sqrt{ 8\cos^2 x \sin^2 x + \sin^4 x + 8 \cos^4 x } dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I need to find the integral of :

$$\int \tan^2 x \sqrt{ 8\cos^2 x \sin^2 x + \sin^4 x + 8 \cos^4 x   } dx$$

I took $1 = sin^2x +\cos^2x $ and got to:

$$ \int{ \tan^2x \sqrt{\sin^4x-8\sin^2x+8} } dx $$

But I don't know where to go from here. Thanks for the help.

Comment: *Mathematica* gives a result that involves elliptic integrals and fills more than a page, so I don't think you're going to do this integral by hand.

Comment: @David G. Stork : Anything's doable by hand if you're willing to take enough time. Would make a great single-question homework set for a calculus course, no?

Comment: ummmmmmmmm...... *no*.

Answer (score 3):

For @The_Sympathizer, who thinks this would be a good single integration problem.  Be my guest!

$$\frac{\sqrt{28 \cos (2 x)+\cos (4 x)+35} \tan (x)}{2
   \sqrt{2}}+\frac{\left(-2+\sqrt{2}\right)^3 \sqrt{\frac{1}{2} \left(2+\sqrt{2}\right)}
   (52 \cos (2 x)+3 \cos (4 x)+9) \sqrt{\frac{-\tan ^2(x)+2 \sqrt{2}-4}{-2+\sqrt{2}}}
   \left(\tan ^2(x)+1\right) \sqrt{\sqrt{2} \tan ^2(x)+2 \tan ^2(x)+4} \sqrt{2 \sqrt{2}
   \tan ^2(x)+3 \tan ^2(x)+2 \sqrt{2}+4} \left(-6 \tan ^5(x)-48 \tan ^3(x)+5 i \Pi
   \left(4+2 \sqrt{2};i \sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{\tan (x)}{\sqrt{2
   \left(2+\sqrt{2}\right)}}\right)|3+2 \sqrt{2}\right) \sqrt{\frac{-2 \tan ^2(x)+4
   \sqrt{2}-8}{-2+\sqrt{2}}} \sqrt{\tan ^2(x)+2 \sqrt{2}+4} \tan ^2(x)-48 \tan (x)+5 i
   \Pi \left(4+2 \sqrt{2};i \sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{\tan (x)}{\sqrt{2
   \left(2+\sqrt{2}\right)}}\right)|3+2 \sqrt{2}\right) \sqrt{\frac{-2 \tan ^2(x)+4
   \sqrt{2}-8}{-2+\sqrt{2}}} \sqrt{\tan ^2(x)+2 \sqrt{2}+4}-i \left(12+\sqrt{2}\right)
   F\left(i \sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{\tan (x)}{\sqrt{2 \left(2+\sqrt{2}\right)}}\right)|3+2
   \sqrt{2}\right) \sqrt{\frac{\tan ^2(x)}{2}+\sqrt{2}+2} \left(\tan ^2(x)+1\right)
   \sqrt{\left(2+\sqrt{2}\right) \tan ^2(x)+4}-6 i \sqrt{2} \left(-1+\sqrt{2}\right)
   E\left(i \sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{\tan (x)}{\sqrt{2 \left(2+\sqrt{2}\right)}}\right)|3+2
   \sqrt{2}\right) \left(\tan ^2(x)+1\right) \sqrt{\tan ^2(x)+2 \sqrt{2}+4}
   \sqrt{\left(2+\sqrt{2}\right) \tan ^2(x)+4}\right)}{8 \sqrt{28 \cos (2 x)+\cos (4
   x)+35} \left(6 \sqrt{2} \sec ^2(x) \sqrt{\frac{-\tan ^2(x)+2 \sqrt{2}-4}{-2+\sqrt{2}}}
   \tan ^8(x)-6 \sec ^2(x) \sqrt{\frac{-\tan ^2(x)+2 \sqrt{2}-4}{-2+\sqrt{2}}} \tan
   ^8(x)+74 \sqrt{2} \sec ^2(x) \sqrt{\frac{-\tan ^2(x)+2 \sqrt{2}-4}{-2+\sqrt{2}}} \tan
   ^6(x)-86 \sec ^2(x) \sqrt{\frac{-\tan ^2(x)+2 \sqrt{2}-4}{-2+\sqrt{2}}} \tan ^6(x)+21
   \sqrt{2 \left(2+\sqrt{2}\right)} \sec ^2(x) \sqrt{\frac{-\tan ^2(x)+2
   \sqrt{2}-4}{-2+\sqrt{2}}} \sqrt{\sqrt{2} \tan ^2(x)+2 \tan ^2(x)+4} \sqrt{2 \sqrt{2}
   \tan ^2(x)+3 \tan ^2(x)+2 \sqrt{2}+4} \tan ^6(x)-30 \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}} \sec ^2(x)
   \sqrt{\frac{-\tan ^2(x)+2 \sqrt{2}-4}{-2+\sqrt{2}}} \sqrt{\sqrt{2} \tan ^2(x)+2 \tan
   ^2(x)+4} \sqrt{2 \sqrt{2} \tan ^2(x)-3 \tan ^2(x)+2 \sqrt{2}+4} \tan ^6(x)+286
   \sqrt{2} \sec ^2(x) \sqrt{\frac{-\tan ^2(x)+2 \sqrt{2}-4}{-2+\sqrt{2}}} \tan ^4(x)-362
   \sec ^2(x) \sqrt{\frac{-\tan ^2(x)+2 \sqrt{2}-4}{-2+\sqrt{2}}} \tan ^4(x)+5 \sqrt{2}
   \sec ^2(x) \sqrt{\sqrt{2} \tan ^2(x)+2 \tan ^2(x)+4} \tan ^4(x)-10 \sec ^2(x)
   \sqrt{\sqrt{2} \tan ^2(x)+2 \tan ^2(x)+4} \tan ^4(x)+63 \sqrt{2
   \left(2+\sqrt{2}\right)} \sec ^2(x) \sqrt{\frac{-\tan ^2(x)+2
   \sqrt{2}-4}{-2+\sqrt{2}}} \sqrt{\sqrt{2} \tan ^2(x)+2 \tan ^2(x)+4} \sqrt{2 \sqrt{2}
   \tan ^2(x)+3 \tan ^2(x)+2 \sqrt{2}+4} \tan ^4(x)-90 \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}} \sec ^2(x)
   \sqrt{\frac{-\tan ^2(x)+2 \sqrt{2}-4}{-2+\sqrt{2}}} \sqrt{\sqrt{2} \tan ^2(x)+2 \tan
   ^2(x)+4} \sqrt{2 \sqrt{2} \tan ^2(x)+3 \tan ^2(x)+2 \sqrt{2}+4} \tan ^4(x)+374
   \sqrt{2} \sec ^2(x) \sqrt{\frac{-\tan ^2(x)+2 \sqrt{2}-4}{-2+\sqrt{2}}} \tan ^2(x)-490
   \sec ^2(x) \sqrt{\frac{-\tan ^2(x)+2 \sqrt{2}-4}{-2+\sqrt{2}}} \tan ^2(x)+45 \sqrt{2}
   \sec ^2(x) \sqrt{\sqrt{2} \tan ^2(x)+2 \tan ^2(x)+4} \tan ^2(x)-70 \sec ^2(x)
   \sqrt{\sqrt{2} \tan ^2(x)+2 \tan ^2(x)+4} \tan ^2(x)+168 \sqrt{2
   \left(2+\sqrt{2}\right)} \sec ^2(x) \sqrt{\frac{-\tan ^2(x)+2
   \sqrt{2}-4}{-2+\sqrt{2}}} \sqrt{\sqrt{2} \tan ^2(x)+2 \tan ^2(x)+4} \sqrt{2 \sqrt{2}
   \tan ^2(x)+3 \tan ^2(x)+2 \sqrt{2}+4} \tan ^2(x)-240 \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}} \sec ^2(x)
   \sqrt{\frac{-\tan ^2(x)+2 \sqrt{2}-4}{-2+\sqrt{2}}} \sqrt{\sqrt{2} \tan ^2(x)+2 \tan
   ^2(x)+4} \sqrt{2 \sqrt{2} \tan ^2(x)+3 \tan ^2(x)+2 \sqrt{2}+4} \tan ^2(x)+156
   \sqrt{2} \sec ^2(x) \sqrt{\frac{-\tan ^2(x)+2 \sqrt{2}-4}{-2+\sqrt{2}}}-208 \sec ^2(x)
   \sqrt{\frac{-\tan ^2(x)+2 \sqrt{2}-4}{-2+\sqrt{2}}}+40 \sqrt{2} \sec ^2(x)
   \sqrt{\sqrt{2} \tan ^2(x)+2 \tan ^2(x)+4}-60 \sec ^2(x) \sqrt{\sqrt{2} \tan ^2(x)+2
   \tan ^2(x)+4}+168 \sqrt{2 \left(2+\sqrt{2}\right)} \sec ^2(x) \sqrt{\frac{-\tan
   ^2(x)+2 \sqrt{2}-4}{-2+\sqrt{2}}} \sqrt{\sqrt{2} \tan ^2(x)+2 \tan ^2(x)+4} \sqrt{2
   \sqrt{2} \tan ^2(x)+3 \tan ^2(x)+2 \sqrt{2}+4}-240 \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}} \sec ^2(x)
   \sqrt{\frac{-\tan ^2(x)+2 \sqrt{2}-4}{-2+\sqrt{2}}} \sqrt{\sqrt{2} \tan ^2(x)+2 \tan
   ^2(x)+4} \sqrt{2 \sqrt{2} \tan ^2(x)+3 \tan ^2(x)+2 \sqrt{2}+4}\right)}$$

Oh:  just for fun, I changed just a single "-" to "+" or vice versa... the kind of error you're likely to make on a homework.  Given this "almost" solution, let's see if you can find that errant sign.... "by hand."

Comment: I am intrigued by your response.  This is apparently beyond my source (Calculus 2nd Ed, 1966, Tom Apostol).  **If** I made no mistake, I set $x =\;$ arctan $\,u\;$ which led to $\;\int \;\frac{u^2}{(u^2 + 1)^2}\sqrt{u^4 + 8}\,du\;$ which apparently led nowhere.  This caused me to ponder $\;\int \,\sqrt{u^4 + 8}\,du\;$ which I also can't crack.  Is there an **online** (free) Calculus resource that discusses my try, and discusses your methods?

Comment: I used *Mathematica*.  You might try Wolfram|Alpha.  In the meantime, see this, to change your view of math education:  https://www.ted.com/talks/conrad_wolfram_teaching_kids_real_math_with_computers

Comment: Why do I think there should be an easier way?

Answer (score 2):

Mathematica gives it in terms of Elliptic integrals as

$$(-8 EllipticE[x, 7/8] + 4 EllipticF[x, 7/8] + 
 Sqrt[9 + 7 Cos[2 x]] Tan[x])/Sqrt[2]$$

This means that the required integral is not expressible in terns of simple trigonometric functions.

Answer (score 1):

$$8\cos^2 x \sin^2 x + \sin^4 x + 8 \cos^4 x =\frac{1}{8} (35+28 \cos (2 x)+\cos (4 x))$$ Using $x=\tan ^{-1}(t)$
$$I=\int \tan^2 x \sqrt{ 8\cos^2 x \sin^2 x + \sin^4 x + 8 \cos^4 x   }\, dx= \int \frac{t^2 \sqrt{t^4+8 t^2+8}}{\left(t^2+1\right)^2}\,dt$$ which leads to nasty elliptic integrals.

I wonder it there could be a typo because with $\tan x$ instead of $\tan^2 x$ there is a rather simple closed form not involving any special function.

**Edit**

Assuming that the problem is as writte, if I had compute this integral over a small range of $t$ (say $0 \leq t \leq 2$, I would build the natural $[4,4]$ Padé approximant of the integrand to get
$$\frac{t^2 \sqrt{t^4+8 t^2+8}}{\left(t^2+1\right)^2}\sim \sqrt{2}\frac{2  t^2+\frac{3 }{5}t^4} { 1+\frac{9 }{5}t^2+\frac{61 }{80}t^4}$$ The integration of the Padé approximant does not make any problem since, after partial fraction decomposition
$$\sqrt{2}\frac{2  t^2+\frac{3 }{5}t^4} { 1+\frac{9 }{5}t^2+\frac{61 }{80}t^4}=\frac{\sqrt{\frac{2}{19}} \left(3432+89 \sqrt{19}\right)}{5 \left(61 t^2+72+4
   \sqrt{19}\right)}-\frac{\sqrt{\frac{2}{19}} \left(3432-89 \sqrt{19}\right)}{5
   \left(61 t^2+72-4 \sqrt{19}\right)}+\frac{3 \sqrt{2}}{5}$$ leading to a term in $t$ plus two arctangents.

Some results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 a & \text{approximation}& \text{exact} \\
 0.25 & 0.01395 & 0.01395 \\
 0.50 & 0.09629 & 0.09629 \\
 0.75 & 0.26487 & 0.26485 \\
 1.00 & 0.49935 & 0.49916 \\
 1.25 & 0.77296 & 0.77212 \\
 1.50 & 1.06641 & 1.06393 \\
 1.75 & 1.36847 & 1.36294 \\
 2.00 & 1.67326 & 1.66295
\end{array}
\right)$$

We could do much better using the next $[6,6]$ Padé approximant which write
$$\frac{t^2 \sqrt{t^4+8 t^2+8}}{\left(t^2+1\right)^2}\sim \sqrt{2}\frac{2 t^2+\frac{38 }{23}t^4+\frac{95 }{368}t^6 }{1+\frac{107 }{46}t^2+\frac{1237 }{736}t^4+\frac{527 }{1472}t^6 }$$ The denominator has three negative roots in $t^2$ which makes by the end one term in $t$ plus three arctangents.

For the same bounds as above, the results would be
$\qquad\qquad\qquad \{0.013945,0.09629,0.26485,0.49916,0.77213,1.06401,1.36316,1.66347\}$